# Drawing path diagrams with R package 'sem' using Graphviz

Tags: r, latex, sweave, structural-equation-model

I use the `sem` package to do my analysis. To draw a path diagram I use the `pathDiagram` function in `sem` to get the code and then use it in `Graphviz` to get the diagram. I have two questions:

```
library(sem)

R.DHP <- readMoments(diag=FALSE, names=c('ROccAsp', 'REdAsp', 'FOccAsp', 
                'FEdAsp', 'RParAsp', 'RIQ', 'RSES', 'FSES', 'FIQ', 'FParAsp'))
    .6247                                                              
    .3269  .3669                                                        
    .4216  .3275  .6404                                      
    .2137  .2742  .1124  .0839                                
    .4105  .4043  .2903  .2598  .1839                          
    .3240  .4047  .3054  .2786  .0489  .2220                    
    .2930  .2407  .4105  .3607  .0186  .1861  .2707              
    .2995  .2863  .5191  .5007  .0782  .3355  .2302  .2950        
    .0760  .0702  .2784  .1988  .1147  .1021  .0931 -.0438  .2087  

model.dhp <- specifyModel()
    RParAsp  -> RGenAsp, gam11,  NA
    RIQ      -> RGenAsp, gam12,  NA
    RSES     -> RGenAsp, gam13,  NA
    FSES     -> RGenAsp, gam14,  NA
    RSES     -> FGenAsp, gam23,  NA
    FSES     -> FGenAsp, gam24,  NA
    FIQ      -> FGenAsp, gam25,  NA
    FParAsp  -> FGenAsp, gam26,  NA
    FGenAsp  -> RGenAsp, beta12, NA
    RGenAsp  -> FGenAsp, beta21, NA
    RGenAsp  -> ROccAsp,  NA,       1
    RGenAsp  -> REdAsp,  lam21,  NA
    FGenAsp  -> FOccAsp,  NA,       1
    FGenAsp  -> FEdAsp,  lam42,  NA
    RGenAsp <-> RGenAsp, ps11,   NA
    FGenAsp <-> FGenAsp, ps22,   NA
    RGenAsp <-> FGenAsp, ps12,   NA
    ROccAsp <-> ROccAsp, theta1, NA
    REdAsp  <-> REdAsp,  theta2, NA
    FOccAsp <-> FOccAsp, theta3, NA
    FEdAsp  <-> FEdAsp,  theta4, NA



sem.dhp <- sem(model.dhp, R.DHP, 329,
    fixed.x=c('RParAsp', 'RIQ', 'RSES', 'FSES', 'FIQ', 'FParAsp'))



pathDiagram(sem.dhp, min.rank='RIQ, RSES, RParAsp, FParAsp, FSES, FIQ', 
    max.rank='ROccAsp, REdAsp, FEdAsp, FOccAsp')
```

1. How do I draw a path diagram directly from `R` using the `pathDiagram` function?
2. How do I include the graph in an `Rnw` file for `Sweave`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to specify a filename (without extension!), see the `file=` argument. As stated in the documentation, it will generated both a `.dot` and PDF file (but set `output.type="dot"` if you only want the graphviz output).

I would use a simple `\includegraphics` command in the Sweave file, after having called the above command. (You may need to adapt the path to find the figure if you don't generate the SEM diagram in the same directory as your master `.Rnw` file.)

**Update**

Given your comment, yes it seems there's a problem running external program from within the function call (`pathDiagram`). So here is a not very elegant solution to generate the path diagram and include it in your Sweave->TeX document.

Here is the Sweave file (`sw.rnw`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
<<echo=TRUE>>=
library(sem)
R.DHP <- readMoments("sem.cov", diag=FALSE, 
                     names=c('ROccAsp', 'REdAsp', 'FOccAsp', 
                       'FEdAsp', 'RParAsp', 'RIQ', 'RSES',  
                       'FSES', 'FIQ', 'FParAsp'))
model.dhp <- specifyModel(file="sem.mod")
sem.dhp <- sem(model.dhp, R.DHP, 329,
               fixed.x=c('RParAsp', 'RIQ', 'RSES', 'FSES', 'FIQ', 'FParAsp'))            
capture.output(pathDiagram(sem.dhp, min.rank='RIQ, RSES, RParAsp, FParAsp, FSES, FIQ', 
            max.rank='ROccAsp, REdAsp, FEdAsp, FOccAsp'), file="sem.dot")
@
<<echo=FALSE>>=
system("dot -Tpdf -o fig1.pdf  sem.dot")
@

And here is the path diagram.

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{fig1}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The files `sem.cov` and `sem.mod` contain the covariance matrix and structural model that were both entered manually in the above example (simple copy/paste in plain text file). I'm not very happy to have to use `capture.output()` because I cannot find a way to mask its call from the chunk. Maybe you'll find a better way to do that (the idea is to use `system()`, and that can easily be masked with `echo=FALSE` in the chunk parameters).

I happened to compile the above document as follows:

```
$ R CMD Sweave sw.rnw
$ R CMD texi2pdf sw.tex
```

[image]

Comment: This extra message `Running  dot -Tpdf -o Path.pdf  Path.dot` failed Sweaving. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. Wonderful solution. Everything is fine except I could not figure out to make invisible the message `Running dot -Tpdf -o Path.pdf Path.dot`. Anyhow this is not a big issue. I've some questions relating to this question: (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39174/4821) and (http://stackoverflow.com/q/8596733/707145). One question is exactly the same as my comment. I'd appreciate if you have a look on these. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I've started bounty and will award you when the waiting time will expire. Thanks for wonderful solution and it will help me a lot in my work. Thanks again.

Comment: @MYaseen208 I didn't see this message: with default parameters for `pathDiagram()` (that is, not using `file=`) graphviz syntax is written to R standard output. Did you put the `file=` inside the call to `pathDiagram()` instead of `capture.output()`? I will think of your other SO question. Regarding the tex.SE one, it's best to simply delete it, IMO (not a good idea to cross-post over SE sites :)