# CFA nice path plots

Tags: r

When I do an EFA from the package psych I can generate really nice path plots with correlations and loadings and such like this:

[image]

using the `fa.diagram` function with the following code:

```
library(psych)
covariances <- ability.cov$cov
correlations <- cov2cor(covariances)
fa.promax <- fa(correlations, nfactors=2, rotate="promax", fm="pa")
fa.diagram(fa.promax, simple=FALSE)
```

I tend to use CFA more than EFA and would like to be able to plot the model with correlations in the same way.  I use the SEM package.  I have tried the `pathDiagram` function but it only produces the code that I can then paste to GVedit from Graphviz.  I do that and the correlations and between factor correlations aren't there. Additionally I don't like cutting and pasting to another program (though the help file from sem for pathDiagram reads: "***To obtain graphics output directly, the dot program must be on the system search path.***"; I don't know what exactly to put in the path to make that happen and if it will even have the correlations anyway?)

**I'd like to be able to make a path diagram similar to what fa.diagram from psych does for EFA.  I'd like to be able to do this in R and not cut and paste.**  I don't care what package you use to do this but I think most people would agree the simpler the better and if it can be done within R it would give great freedom of the choice of graphics device.

Here is some sample code for a CFA model to work with:

```
dat3 <- read.table(url("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/61803503/Proj_2b.dat"), 
            header=T, strip.white = T, as.is=FALSE, 
            na.strings= c("999", "NA", " "))

NHSDA.cov <- cov(dat3)

ete.mod <- specifyModel() 
F1 -> item3, lam1, NA 
F1 -> item5, lam2, NA 
F1 -> item9, lam3, NA 
F1 -> item10, lam4, NA 
F2 -> item4, lam5, NA 
F2 -> item13, lam6, NA 
F2 -> item14, lam7, NA 
F2 -> item15, lam8, NA 
F3 -> item1, lam9, NA 
F3 -> item6, lam10, NA 
F3 -> item7, lam11, NA 
F3 -> item11, lam12, NA 
F3 -> item12, lam13, NA 
F4 -> item2, lam14, NA 
F4 -> item8, lam15, NA 
F4 -> item16, lam16, NA 
F4 -> item17, lam17, NA 
item1 <-> item1, e1, NA 
item2 <-> item2, e2, NA 
item3 <-> item3, e3, NA 
item4 <-> item4, e4, NA 
item5 <-> item5, e5, NA 
item6 <-> item6, e6, NA 
item7 <-> item7, e7, NA 
item8 <-> item8, e8, NA 
item9 <-> item9, e9, NA 
item10 <-> item10, e10, NA 
item11 <-> item11, e11, NA 
item12 <-> item12, e12, NA 
item13 <-> item13, e13, NA 
item14 <-> item14, e14, NA 
item15 <-> item15, e15, NA 
item16 <-> item16, e16, NA 
item17 <-> item17, e17, NA 
F1 <-> F1, NA, 1
F2 <-> F2, NA, 1
F3 <-> F3, NA, 1
F4 <-> F4, NA, 1
F2 <-> F1, rF1F2 #1
F3 <-> F1, rF1F3 #2
F4 <-> F1, rF1F4 #3
F3 <-> F2, rF2F3 #4
F4 <-> F2, rF2F4 #5
F4 <-> F3, rF3F4 #6

ete.sem <- sem(ete.mod, NHSDA.cov, nrow(dat3)) 
(ete.SUM <- summary(ete.sem))

pathDiagram(ete.sem) #the attempt thus far
```

*Running R 2.14.2 on Win 7*

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8585108/707145) that I asked a while ago.

Comment: @MYaseen208 it sounds like there were some issues.  Were you able to generate the plots within R?  And did they have the correlations?  The solution to this doesn't have to be `pathDiagram`.

Comment: See my Edited answer. I do believe you will get correlations too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this:

```
pathDiagram(
              model=ete.sem
            , file="PathDiagram"
            , max.rank=paste("item", 1:17, sep="")
            , ignore.double=FALSE
            , edge.labels="values"
            , size=c(8, 8)
            , node.font=c("Helvetica", 10)
            , edge.font=c("Helvetica", 10)
            , rank.direction="LR"
            , digits=3
            , standardize=TRUE
            , graphics.fmt="pdf"
            )
```

This will generate  `PathDiagram.pdf` in your working directory. I don't know anyway to display the graph in R.

[image]

Comment: @MYaseen2008  This produces a word (.doc) file in the working directory.  There is no pdf (I think this has to do with the question I asked about having dot in my path; I'm not sure what to put in the path).  The code in the word document does produce a graphic output with correlations.  Thank you.+1  I'll mark this answer as correct when the pdf issue is resolved.

Comment: The pdf issue couldn't be resolved so I marked it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. The application [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php) needs to be installed, which creates then a PDF file out of the .dot file. This is also explained in the help file of the R package *pathDiagram*.